# MassTransit override ConversationId during Publish

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Is there any way to override or set to null MassTransit's build in fields during message publish?
For my particular case I need to set ConversationId to null during message publish on my integration test. To publish message I'm using

```
  await Bus.Publish<ITestContractMessage>(new {TestName = "Hello World"});
```

I've tried to configure bus using ConfigurePublish method but it didn't help.

```
  cfg.ConfigurePublish(x => x.UseSendExecute(ctx => ctx.ConversationId = null));
```

Is there any ideas on how can I acheace it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it, or any of the headers, using:

```
await Bus.Publish<ITestContractMessage>(new {
    TestName = "Hello World!"
}, context => context.ConversationId = null);
```

You can set any of the other headers as well.

Since the ConversationId is specified prior to your delegate being invoked, you should be able to clear it. At least, that was the design, I guess you'll find out if I did it right!

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! But unfortunatelly this approach does not work for ConversationId because, looks like, it populates after delegate invocation.
Some of the rest of the headers, for example SourceAddress might be changed this way.

Comment: I'll check the filter ordering and fix what I find broken. It should set it before the developer has access, so that it can be overridden.

Comment: Yeah, it forces a `ConversationId` if it isn't present, so there is no way to sent it with null. It will generate a new one if you set it to null, however.